# How to calculate readibility scores easily or how can i write a function for that?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

I have to calculate readability score of a text document. Is there a package or inbuilt function. Everything on internet seems too complex. Can any one help me with that or how to write my own function?

I have done pre processing of text, calculated the tfidf of document but I want to find the readability score or fog index of the document. I tried using code available on other platform but it didn't work

```
def text_process(mess):

    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

    #nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

    text = [word for word in tokens if word not in stops]

    text = [wl.lemmatize(word) for word in mess]

    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

import pandas as pd

vect = TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf_matrix = vect.fit_transform(df["comments"].head(10000))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(),columns=vect.get_feature_names())

print(df1)
```

I don't know how to get the desired results of readability scores. I would appreciate if someone would help me

Comment: try to read about `nltk` for python

Comment: oh and also this https://pypi.org/project/textstat/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `automated_readability_index()` from `textstat` to get the score you want

```py
import textstat

text = 'your text'

score = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)

print (score)
```

Output:

```
-1.7
```

The higher the `score` is the better your text is.

OR you can also try using `flesch_reading_ease()` from `textstat`, i found it useful for my `nlp` related task(evaluating bot's conversation level)

For more info here is [textstat's](https://pypi.org/project/textstat/) documentation.

Comment: `import textstat`

`text = data["comments"]`

`score = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)`

`print (score)`

Comment: the text has to be taken from a pandas dataframe and when i use the above code, it gives me an error saying `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-5-6d25577bcfde> in <module>
        3 text = data["comments"].head(20)
        ----> 5 score = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)
                6 
                7 print (score)
 This is the entire error

Comment: how you iterate through your dataset is not my problem, i found a way for you to get a readability score of a string, how you use it later is not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API. It's quite simple.

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.apyhub.com")

payload = "{\n    \"text\": \" ADD-TEXT-HERE \"\n}"

headers = {
    'apy-token': "YOUR-SECRET-APY-TOKEN", // Replace it with your secret apy token
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/extract/text/readability-score", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

You can generate your free apy-token from [here](https://apyhub.com/utility/readability-scores)